# Unity not destroying object on one click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So im making this building tycoon kinda game and i experienced this issue

```
    public GameObject particle;

    public GameObject[] building;

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if(GameManager.Manager.buildingID >= 0)
        {
            Instantiate(building[GameManager.Manager.buildingID], transform.position, 
            Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate(particle, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
```

When i click on it it instantiates the prefabs but does not destroy the object that i clicked on
But if i click it on again then it destroys it

I even tried:
DestroyImmediate(gameObject);
Destroy(this.gameObject);
and
DestroyImmediate(this.gameObject); (like these make any difference but still tried it)

I decided to go to destroying it cause when i used bools to check if it was build on that space, itll just reset the bool to False after like 3 - 5 seconds

I even tried creating a new C# script and pasting the code in

I have no idea whats going on, even without instantiating the objects it still does not delete it in one click

Comment: Your code looks ok, any errors? `particle` is null is my guess. Which part of your code is causing this: `itll just reset the bool to False after like 3 - 5 seconds`?

Comment: no code, i checked every script and every line and i didnt saw = false in it, also no the particle is not null

EDIT: i've read this wrong
So on my other script till i commented it
I had it set to True after it has been clicked on, it sets to true but then it resets to false 3 - 5 seconds later, no line of code resets it to false, even tried restarting unity and creating a new C# file, nothing worked

Comment: Some other part of your code is likely reinstantiating this hotspot object in that case - Unity won't randomly unset a variable on its own.

Comment: @LukeBriggs i checked it 11th time now, theres nothing

Comment: The bug exists so there is definitely something, just not in this code. All I know is if particle is not null, then the above code will work as expected.

Comment: ill try test it with just detecting mouse click

Comment: @LukeBriggs I tried void Update() it works fine with destroying an object but not with OnMouseOver or OnMouseDown

Comment: i tried:
```
private bool mouseOver;

void OnMouseOver(){
     mouseOver = true;
}

void Update(){
    if(mouseOver){

           if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
            {
                if (GameManager.Manager.buildingID >= 0)
                {
                    Instantiate(building[GameManager.Manager.buildingID], 
                    transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    Instantiate(particle, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    Destroy(gameObject);
                }
            }
    }
}
```
stilSameError

Comment: i have NO idea why is this happening, i checked everything, even made a different file even trying every way i can think of, its just not working

Comment: New scene, create a cube, add script with `void OnMouseDown() { Destroy(gameObject); }` - works completely fine; definitely got something else going on in your scene

Comment: @LukeBriggs very strange, it works with the cube, probably because the stuff you had to click on was in a prefab as a child

Answer (score 0):

Where is this script attached? When you use

```
Destroy(gameObject);
```

gameObject refers to the GameObject that the script is attached to, not necessarily the object that you are clicking on, so this script should be destroying the object that it is attached to.